# Yii Bootstrap TbMenu in Navbar events

Tags: events, twitter-bootstrap, yii, navbar

I'm beginning to work on Bootstrap in Yii framework and finding some difficulties in making it work the way I want to. 
And have not found anything useful in the docs, although I might have missed something.
I have the navbar like this:

```
<?php $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbNavbar', array(
'collapse'=>true, // requires bootstrap-responsive.css
'fixed'=>'none',
'brand'=>false,
'items'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.widgets.TbMenu',
        'items'=>array(
            array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>'#', 'active'=>true),
            array('label'=>'Link', 'url'=>'#'),
            array('label'=>'Dropdown', 'url'=>'#', 'items'=>array(
                array('label'=>'Action', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'Another action', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'Something else here', 'url'=>'#'),
                '---',
                array('label'=>'NAV HEADER'),
                array('label'=>'Separated link', 'url'=>'#'),
                array('label'=>'One more separated link', 'url'=>'#'),
            )),
        ),
    ),
),
));
?>
```

By default submenu drop out by Click event, but I want to submenu drop out at mouseover event. How do it, please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Im using bootstrap with Yii for a while and submenus popups automatically. Check also this link http://www.bootply.com/60842 which shows that bootstrap submenus popups automatically on mouseover.

You will be probably overriding/missing some css/javascript files. Also check console if your page has no errors after loading.

Answer (score 0):

Find bootstrap.js in the asset folder of the bootstrap extension folder.

Replace the following (rows 797- 800) :

```
.on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
.on('mouseover.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
.on('mouseover.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
.on('keydown.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
```

to becomes

```
.on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
.on('mouseover.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
.on('mouseover.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
.on('keydown.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
```

In order to work, you have to clean the asset folder in the main directory to generate once from the asset you've just changed.